# Get Max value from List<myType>

Tags: list, c#-2.0

I have List `List<MyType>`, my type contains `Age` and `RandomID`

Now I want to find the maximum age from this list.

What is the simplest and most efficient way?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Okay, so if you don't have LINQ, you could hard-code it:

```
public int FindMaxAge(List<MyType> list)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty list");
    }
    int maxAge = int.MinValue;
    foreach (MyType type in list)
    {
        if (type.Age > maxAge)
        {
            maxAge = type.Age;
        }
    }
    return maxAge;
}
```

Or you could write a more general version, reusable across lots of list types:

```
public int FindMaxValue<T>(List<T> list, Converter<T, int> projection)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty list");
    }
    int maxValue = int.MinValue;
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        int value = projection(item);
        if (value > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

You can use this with:

```
// C# 2
int maxAge = FindMaxValue(list, delegate(MyType x) { return x.Age; });

// C# 3
int maxAge = FindMaxValue(list, x => x.Age);
```

Or you could use [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge) :)

In each case, you can return the if block with a simple call to `Math.Max` if you want. For example:

```
foreach (T item in list)
{
    maxValue = Math.Max(maxValue, projection(item));
}
```

Comment: The delegate type could you please give example

Comment: @Shrivallabh: I don't know what you mean, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think he needs some elaboration for the `delegate` example. I was not able to understand that too, that's why I had to go with the 2nd method that you used in the same block. The FindMax thing.

Comment: @Shrivallabh: Well seeing as the OP accepted the answer, I suspect they understood it. It's not clear what you didn't understand about it - do you understand anonymous methods and lambda expressions?

Answer (score 140):

Assuming you have access to LINQ, and `Age` is an `int` (you may also try `var maxAge` - it is more likely to compile):

```
int maxAge = myTypes.Max(t => t.Age);
```

If you also need the `RandomID` (or the whole object), a quick solution is to use [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) from [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
MyType oldest = myTypes.MaxBy(t => t.Age);
```

Answer (score 40):

```
int max = myList.Max(r => r.Age);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx

Comment: Stating the obvious but...In order to use this in .net 4.0 and VS2010 you need "using System.Linq;". Right clicking on the error does not give the "Resolve" option.

Answer (score 18):

```
var maxAge = list.Max(x => x.Age);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting code in your solution, it is helpful to explain how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context

Comment: where is max method ?

Comment: @BrijeshMavani `System.Linq`. [Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max)

Answer (score 9):

```
thelist.Max(e => e.age);
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to use System.Linq as previously described

```
using System.Linq;

public int GetHighestValue(List<MyTypes> list)
{
    return list.Count > 0 ? list.Max(t => t.Age) : 0; //could also return -1
}
```

This is also possible with a Dictionary

```
using System.Linq;

public int GetHighestValue(Dictionary<MyTypes, OtherType> obj)
{
    return obj.Count > 0 ? obj.Max(t => t.Key.Age) : 0; //could also return -1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest is actually just `Age.Max()`, you don't need any more code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4}; //or any other type
myList.Sort();
int greatestValue = myList[ myList.Count - 1 ];
```

You basically let the `Sort()` method to do the job for you instead of writing your own method. Unless you don't want to sort your collection.

Comment: This is not going to work if that is not the desired operation, especially if the int value in the list is greater than the size of the list.

Comment: The value can be anything. We are getting it based on its location in the collection, not the actual value of it. For instance, `List<int>(){ 5, 10, 15, 20 }` whenever we sort this collection, the number 20 is always at the last index, unless we sort it descendingly.