# How to find the maximum priced product in a website like walmart using webdriver when decimal values are in the price?

Tags: sorting, selenium, webdriver

In the walmart website how do i find the maximum priced bag?

The URL is : https://www.walmart.com/browse/clothing/handbags/5438_1045799_1045800?sort=price_high

Code for getting prices and storing in list:

```
public class Handbag {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/browse/clothing/handbags/5438_1045799_1045800?sort=price_high");

    List<WebElement> values=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='price price-display']"));

    for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)

    {  String value = values.get(i).getText();

    System.out.println(value); // Display all values
```

The price of the bags are in decimal format so how to sort and find the maximum price?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464934/get-max-value-from-listmytype), you can some idea.

Comment: The post doesn't talk about how to handle decimal values

Comment: What, specifically, is the trouble working with decimal values? It's unclear to me what you're having a problem with. Is it that the values are strings and you want to turn them into numbers so that they sort correctly?

Comment: From the above code I get the list of prices in webelement form..but after that I am not able to convert the list of webelements to float in order to sort them.