# Find highest number in .csv file and display it

Tags: c#

What can I do that this Programm will output the highest number of my csv file?
Currently it displays the value in the in the Brackets of the `.Content` line

```
private void BtnAuswerten_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("H:/Projekte/MaxTemp2/MaxTemp/MaxTemp/temps.csv"))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        List<string> listC = new List<string>();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
            listC.Add(values[2]);
        }

        lblAusgabe.Content = (string.Join(",", listA[5], listB[5], listC[5]));
    }
}
"EDIT
Sorry for not elaborating more, what i'm trying to do is get the highest value of the last column of the values below.
i want to check all of them save the one line with the highest 3rd column value. 
for example if we only had the first two lines of the csv below it would output S2,2020-07-01 07:30:43,42.4 
because 42.4 is higher than 40.4.
I hope this answers some of the questions on what im trying to do here.

S1,2020-07-01 07:30:42,40.4
S2,2020-07-01 07:30:43,42.4
S3,2020-07-01 07:30:24,28.4
S4,2020-07-01 07:30:25,29.8
SB,2020-07-01 07:43:34,20.4
S3,2020-07-01 08:44:12,28.9
S2,2020-07-01 08:44:22,43.7
SD,2020-07-01 08:44:19,32.4
S4,2020-07-01 08:45:48,30.9
S1,2020-07-01 09:12:25,41.4
SB,2020-07-01 09:13:42,26.4
S2,2020-07-01 09:13:52,44.1
S1,2020-07-01 09:14:28,44.3
S2,2020-07-01 09:15:32,45.9
S4,2020-07-01 10:31:16,38.7
S3,2020-07-01 10:32:42,31.5
S1,2020-07-01 10:32:59,48.4
S3,2020-07-01 10:36:32,37.1
S4,2020-07-01 11:04:45,40.2
S3,2020-07-01 11:04:52,38.4
S1,2020-07-01 11:05:58,51.2
S2,2020-07-01 12:22:13,55.8
S1,2020-07-01 12:22:45,52.4
S1,2020-07-01 12:23:34,44.4
S4,2020-07-01 12:30:26,44.1
SD,2020-07-01 13:33:54,45.4
S1,2020-07-01 13:33:45,50.0
S3,2020-07-01 13:34:25,44.7
SB,2020-07-01 14:35:59,30.0
S4,2020-07-01 14:44:57,48.1
S1,2020-07-01 16:31:38,59.5
S2,2020-07-01 16:32:18,59.4
SB,2020-07-01 16:33:26,33.4
S4,2020-07-01 17:32:30,49.2
"
```

Comment: we don't know your csv and in particular what "the value in the Brackets of the .Content-line" is. Please share some sample-data and what result you get exactly.

Comment: see: [Get Max value from List<myType>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464934/get-max-value-from-listmytype)  BTW: If the column contains numeric data, you should change `string` to an appropriate data type...

Comment: Without knowing how your CSV looks like, this is quite hard to answer ....

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of the initial CSV file and the desired output, please?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a DataTable instead of three independent lists:

[...]

```
    DataTable dtValues = new DataTable();
    dtValues.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
    dtValues.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
    dtValues.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
    
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        dtValues.Rows.Add(values[0],values[1],values[1]);
    }
    
    dtValues.DefaultView.Sort = "Column1 DESC";
    dtValues = dtValues.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

[...]

That snippet assumes that the first column contains the value you want to sort.  But I'm sure you can adapt it for your needs.

When you try to print your highest value on `lblAusgabe`, do it like that:

```
lblAusgabe.Content = (string.Join(",", dtValues.Rows[0].Field<int>("Column1"), dtValues.Rows[0].Field<string>("Column2"), dtValues.Rows[0].Field<string>("Column3")));
```

Comment: And where exactly do you get the maximum? And the maximum of *what*?

Comment: In this case you get the max value of column1 in the first row. So you can access it by `dtValues.Rows[0].Field<int>("Column1")`

Comment: this is not really a "whrong" solution, however it's barely the best one. Getting the max out of some list-based data can be achieved far easier...

Comment: How do you know the highest value will be in column1?

Comment: The problem is: The question lacks many important details, so that it can currently not be answerd thoroughly. And just guessing and assuming what OP eventually meant, probably won't do any good because it might lead OP in a wrong direction. So you are *assumig* the sort attribute is in the first colum. But what if (just another possible *assumption*) the whole CSV (ie all three columns) consists only of numbers and the highest can be in any of them? How will your answer solve this problem?

Comment: It's the output line at the end of his snippet which makes it look for me like the OP does not know, that those lists are independent to each other. Yet he/she wants to output all values of the csv line with the highest value.

Comment: Furthermore OP speaks of "finding the hightest number and display it", yet in the code *three*  values are printed. That doesn't fit together. So instead of jumping to conclusions about what OP means, before anwsering, one should help OP to get clear about the requirements, because this step alone often helps OP in finding a solution to the problem ...